# Different results back accessing the same php json request from android and pc web browser

Tags: java, android, api, http-post

I am having a problem where when I put the querying URL into a web browser on my Mac the API send the data back as I am expecting but when I use the exact same URL within my app on android I get the following error: `{"SC":"400","VSM":"Incorrect parameter passed on URL","VERNUM":"1.2"}`. It is just a simple test to see if the database in my app is up to date. Is this an API problem or something i'm doing wrong in the app? I have no control over the API functionality so if it's a problem with that then I will have to get somebody else to sort it out. the code I am using is below.

```
String URL = "http://Url.com/?p=api&request=check_for_changes";
Log.v("Value", URL);
JSONObject jsonObjSend = new JSONObject();
try
{
    jsonObjSend.put("dataset_version_number", 1.1);
    // Output the JSON object we're sending to Logcat:
    Log.v("Response", jsonObjSend.toString(2));
}
catch (JSONException e)
{
    Log.i("Response", "Error happened here");
}

try 
{
    jsonObjRecv = HttpClient.SendHttpPost(URL, jsonObjSend);
    Log.v("SC", jsonObjRecv.get("SC").toString());
}
catch (JSONException e){

}
```

The `HttpClient` object is from a class I have used many times before to just read the response from the server so i'm not going to post the code on here as it's not relevent and quite long.

Comment: Did you already check that your PC browser gets a proper result when you change its identifers to match the android browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer come in the form of me being an idiot and trying to use a `POST` Request on a URL which doesnt accept JSON and only needs a `GET` Request. So I only need to query the URL and get the response rather than try and send the data via a `POST`using JSON.